# Live map with changing data

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, javascript, openlayers

I develop a map with live data. The data is stored in a PostGIS (PostgreSQL) database. Geoserver is used to provide the WMS.

My problem is that I need to redraw my layer, let's say, every 5 seconds to see changes of the data. The most common way seems to be something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var params = source.getParams();
    params.t = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    source.updateParams(params);
    source.refresh();
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    map.updateSize();},200);
}, 5000);
```

Unfortunatelly it does not work for me. New data is shown only if I zoom or move the map. I cannot see GET requests from the browser.

How can I update my map?

Comment: please expand on what doesn't work - are new requests made or does the browser cache get in the way?

Comment: looks like your setting the refresh rate but you need to execute the action like window.setInterval(reload, 10000);

Comment: @iant For me it looks like no GET request is send.

Comment: @Mapperz This is not the problem. It is similiar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)